# C#: Extended WPF Toolkit - Customizing Font Size Of Caption In a MessageBox

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I'm utilizing the WPF Toolkit MessageBox, because it easily allows me to make the text bigger than the standard size text like what shows in the Standard WPF MessageBox.

However, I can find no way to increase the size of the text in the caption/Title Bar of the WPF Toolkit MessageBox. The result is that it looks very funny with large text (desired) in the main part of the WPF Toolkit MessageBox Window, but comparatively small text in the caption/Title Bar part.

I'm looking for a quick and easy fix here. I'm not really interested in writing new classes and a bunch of code, etc.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, how did you increase the font size of the content alone, but not the TitleBar. I have written a style for WPFToolKit messagebox, and in that I have set the FontSize. It is common for both(content and TitleBar).

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:MessageBox}">
<Setter Property="CaptionForeground" Value="White" />
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
</Style>
```

where toolkit is the namespace added for WPFToolkit.

Comment: The same was not true for me, but I downloaded the build from about three or four weeks ago. I believe there were comments on there about how both the caption and content were being affected by Styles for the content, but it was listed as a "bug" that must have gotten fixed.

Anyways, I rolled my own MessageDialog that supports touch and includes XAML graphics instead of raster images. I really like it.